# Remove last characters from string in hiveql

Tags: string, hive, hiveql

I need help with Hive, I've tried a lot functions in Hive and I havent been able to do what I need to do.

Look at the following example:
3231220-9

I just need to keep everything but the '-9' the rest is not needed.

Please help!

Comment: Is it always "-9" you want to remove? Can you be more precise in the requirements and give a few more examples?

Comment: actually is always the '-' with the one character that comes afterwards....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep only the digits up to the first hyphen or other non-digit, then:

```
regexp_replace(myfield,'[^0-9].*','')
```

If it is always a hyphen with one character following at the end:

```
regexp_replace(myfield,'-.$','')
```

Comment: I will give this one a try! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` also:

```
hive> select split('3231220-9','-')[0];
OK
3231220
Time taken: 3.994 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at elegant as split() function but this will also work:

```
select substr('12345678-9', 1, instr('12345678-9','-')-1);
Result: 12345678
```